# What is the difference between erase and restore on macOS Disk Utility?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, restore, ui

I want to re-format an external hard drive, but I'm not sure what the difference is between 'restore' or 'erase'.

Does erase remove all files, or not?

I don't want to lose the files, but I cannot back up the entire Volume, for lack of storage. SSDs are on the way, but will not arrive for a week.

I found this answer online but can't be sure of its correctness:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3111247?answerId=32268374022#32268374022

What I generally do to re-activate a hard drive that could be stuck on a task. Is the following on terminal:

`ps aux | grep fsck`

`sudo kill -9 [task number]`

but this solution does not format or enable journaling. In addition, it limits the result by removing the drive's capability to re-write. Forcing me to apply:

**Disk Utility>First Aid** (so far, sometimes it takes a long time, others very long).

I feel like I'm asking many questions here.

But I simply wish to know if erase or restore will enable journaling without losing all your data

(if **Disk Utility** can do this from their GUI would be a lifesaver).

But I'm willing to learn other solutions in the terminal as to how I found out:

`ps aux | grep fsck`

Comment: If you want to keep the files, then don't do anything to the drive that involves Disk Utility.

Comment: This question is a bit confused. You are asking about erase vs restore, yet you haven't told us what it actually is you are trying to fix, only some solutions you already tried that didn't work. We can't tell whether that you tried *should* work, because we don't know what problem you are trying to solve. Your ps aux trick will find & kill fsck if it is running… but if it's running you should let it fix what it's trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

**Erase** will erase all data.

**Restore** will erase all data and replace it with data from wherever you choose as the source for the restore.

So in both cases, you will lose all data on the disk, partition, container or volume. The data will be gone.

The only caveat is that depending on the current state of the disk (e.g. encryption) *some* of the data *might be* recoverable using 3rd party file recovery software or data recovery service. You don't want to do that!

Answer (score 0):

> I simply wish to know if erase or restore will enable journaling without losing all your data

**No, you will lose all data**:

- Using **Erase** on `Disk Utility` to format a volume will delete all existing data.
- Using **Restore** on `Disk Utility` will also delete all existing data on a volume, as it copies data from another image of a volume.

---

There is a much simpler way to enable *Journaling* in an **existing** volume with the [macOS Extended or APFS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dsku19ed921c/mac) file system. This can be done using `Disk Utility` or through the `Terminal`.

**Enable *Journaling* using `Disk Utility`**

1. Open `Disk Utility` from *Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility*.
2. From the list of disks on the left-hand side, select the name of the volume on which you wish to enable journaling.
3. Then click on **File** > **Enable Journaling**.

**Note**:

- It is recommended to run **First Aid** on the disk before enabling journaling.
- To enable / disable journaling on a boot disk (**Macintosh HD**), you have to run `Disk Utility` through Recovery or from another installation disk.

**Enable *Journaling* using `Terminal`**

1. Login to macOS as an admin user.
2. Open `Terminal` from *Applications > Utilities > Terminal*.
3. Type the following command: `sudo diskutil enableJournal /dev/diskXsY` and press the <kbd>return</kbd> key.

**Note**: In /dev/disk**X**s**Y**, '**X**' is the disk number and '**Y**' is the disk's slice / volume number.

*(Since you didn't specify a macOS version, note that all instructions here are specific to macOS Mojave 10.14 and may vary slightly on other macOS versions)*.